# verify if email exist(php) and send verification email (php)

Tags: php, mysql, email

Hi guys im building a complete registration system with sign in, log in, send verification email, etc. I have some issues that are as follow:

1. I wanted to check if the email already exists in the database or not, but it did not give me any error message and the same email can be used to register again and again
2. I wanted to be able to send a verification email once the user successfully registered and this is what l got:

Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Note question 2: lm having this problem because l did not change : $mail->SMTPSecure = '????'; and : $mail->Port = ????;

the reason is that l have not yet setup a domain name and hosting to be able to get or modify those info, so im using a personal email, So what should l used for the SMTPSecure and the $mail->Port?.

The code to both issues:

```
<?php

require_once('connect.php');
require_once('functions.php');
include('config.php');

// $error = ""; No need to declare this variable

if(isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST)){

    //DEFINING FIELD INPUTS VARIABLES AND SECURING THE DATA
    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['fname']);
    $verification_key = md5($firstname);
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['lname']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
    $password =($_POST['password']);
    $confirmpassword =($_POST['confirmpassword']);

    //check email validation
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){

        $error = "Veillez enter un courriel valide";
    }
    else if(strlen($password) < 8){

        $error = "Mot de passe doit être au moins 8 characters";
    }
    else if($password !== $confirmpassword){

        //CHECKING IF THE EMAIL ALREADY EXISTS IN THE DATABASE

        $fmsg = ""; 
        $emailsql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
        $emailres = mysqli_query($connection, $emailsql);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($emailres);
        if($count == 1){
            $fmsg .= "Cet courriel existe deja, veuillez utiliser un autre!";
        }

        $error = "Mots de passe ne correspondent pas";
    }
    else{

        //md5 encryption: password security
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $confirmpassword = md5($_POST['confirmpassword']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, password, confirmpassword, verification_key) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$password', '$confirmpassword', '$verification_key')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    if($result){
        $smsg = "Enregistrement réussie";
        // $id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);


        //ADDING PHPMAILER TO SEND A VERIFICATION EMAIL once the user successfully registered
            require 'PHPmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

                $mail = new PHPMailer;

                $mail->isSMTP();                                      
                $mail->Host = 'smtphost';  
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
                $mail->Username = 'smtpuser';                 
                $mail->Password = 'smtppass';                          
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  // make sure to change  the smtp secure to your security type (for example ssl)                                        
                $mail->Port = 587; // make sure to change the port number                                   

                $mail->setFrom('bafosth@yahoo.fr', 'Afro-1');
                $mail->addAddress('bachwu@gmail.com', 'Bachir Amadou');    

                $mail->Subject = 'Verifiez votre courriel';
                $mail->Body = "http://localhost/fost/verify.php?key=$verification_key&id=$id";
                $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

                if(!$mail->send()) {
                    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
                    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                } else {
                    echo 'Message has been sent';
                }// end of script to the verification email


    }
    else{
        $fmsg = "Enregistrement échoué";
    }
}

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="description" content="Montreal - User Reviews and Recommendations of Top Restaurants, Shopping, Nightlife, Entertainment, immigration lawyers, associations, web designers, Services and More at Afro-one">
        <meta name="keywords" content="
        Afro-one, recommendation, montreal, laval, quebec, ottawa, toronto, local, business, review, friend, restaurant, buffet, beauty salon, container shipping, shops, real estate agent, realtor, association, community, night-club, car dealer">
        <meta name="author" content="Bachir Amadou Seydou">
        <title>Afro-1</title>
        <script src="./javascript/script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="form-wrapper">
            <div id="home">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Accueil</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <!--display the alert messages: success or failed-->
            <?php if(isset($smsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> <?php echo $smsg; ?> </div> <?php } ?>
            <?php if(isset($fmsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <?php echo $fmsg; ?> </div> <?php } ?>
            <?php if(isset($error)){ ?><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <?php echo $error; ?> </div> <?php } ?>


            <div id="menu">
                <a href="signup.php">S'enregistrer</a>
                <a href="login.php">Se connecter</a>
                <a href="reset.php">Mot de passe oublié</a>
            </div>
            <div id="form-signup">
                <form id="signup-form" name="sign-up" action="signup.php" method="POST">
                        <h1>Créez votre profile</h1>
                        <p>
                            <input type="text" name="fname" class="signup-input" required="required" placeholder="Prenom*" value="<?php if(isset($firstname) & !empty($firstname)) {echo $firstname; } ?>" >
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <input type="text" name="lname" class="signup-input" required="required" placeholder="Nom*" value="<?php if(isset($lastname) & !empty($lastname)) {echo $lastname; } ?>" >
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="signup-input" required="required" placeholder="Courriel*" value="<?php if(isset($email) & !empty($email)) {echo $email; } ?>" >
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="signup-input" required="required" placeholder="Mot de passe*">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" class="signup-input" required="required" placeholder="Confirmez mot de passe*">
                        </p>
                        <p class="agree"> En vous inscrivant, vous acceptez <br>les<a href="condition.php"> Conditions d'utilisation</a><br> et la <a href="politic.php">Politique de confidentialité</a> d'Afro-1.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <input type="submit" class="signup-btn" name="btn-signup" value="Valider">
                        </p>
                    </div><!--END OF PHASE-1-->
                </form> <!--END OF SIGN-UP-->
            </div><!--END FO ALLFORM-->
        </div><!--END OF FORM-WRAPPER-->        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You only check for a duplicate email if the passwords don't match.  If they *do* match, you never check.  As for the email, what do you mean by "personal email"?  Regardless of what email service you use, the code needs to know the SMTP connection details.  What are they for your service?

Comment: Seems like you are trying to send an email without a SMTP server (unless you have a SMTP server set up as `smtphost`).

Comment: Also... Why store the "confirm password" field?  Do you really need *two* copies of everyone's password?  Won't those values *always* be identical?

Comment: just a note that you're leaving yourself vulnerable to SQL injection attacks with that code - **never** use client-side data that hasn't been escaped in your SQL (have a look at using prepared statements instead), and also you shouldn't be using MD5 to hash passwords - use PHP's built-in `password_hash()` and  `password_verify()` methods.

Comment: Thank you guys for the replies. @ David, im using gmail, so how do l get the SMTP connection details?

Comment: @Bachir: Google "gmail smtp settings".